# How to run .rb script using jmeter gui

Tags: ruby, jmeter

I am trying to perform load test using jmeter. I have my script to extract and generate .json output file which is using ruby. Now i want to use this output.json ( which changes with every thread event) in jmeter and run it with 100 threads. How do I call .rb using jmeter gui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to invoke whatever external command or program from JMeter test script.

Example configuration:

[image]

Change:

- `c:\apps\ruby\bin\ruby.exe` to the actual path to your `ruby` executable
- `c:\temp\script.rb` to the actual path of your .rb script

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute ruby in JMeter using jruby script engine

1. [Dowonload](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjrubyenginejar.htm) jruby-engine.jar
2. Copy to JMeter lib directory with ruby relevant jars (as jruby-core)
3. In JSR223 choose language as `jruby`
4. Write your ruby script and run test

Notice that JRuby find predefined variable using $ prefix:

```
$log.info("Hello from JRuby");
```